# How to run Git commands on remote repository

Tags: git, repository

I am trying to code an simple PHP application which will retrieve some information from the remote Git repositories with terminal commands. I do not want to create a local working copy or repository. I only want to read information from remote repositories (browse tree, commit history, file diffs, download file), so it will be a read only connection.

What I need to do is to run a series of simple commands like those in SVN: log, ls, diff, cat,..

I have allready done that for SVN and it was easy. Usually commands were similar to this format:

```
svn --user myusername --pass mypassword --non-interactive command -r revisionNumber urlToRemoteRepository
```

My question is how to get similar information from Git repositories with terminal commands only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would SSH into the server using PuTTY (windows) or the ssh command (Mac/Linux) and run them from the command line there.

Comment: this is overkill for the end goal that the user wants to attain.

Answer (score 2):

This is not the preferred workflow in git.

```
git fetch
```

Then use

```
gitk --all
```

or

```
git log --all --decorate --graph # optionally --oneline if there's lots there
```

to investigate what you got. Learn tree-ish syntax, branch specifications etc.

hope this helps